# How did the word "chunter" come about?

Tags: etymology

Did it arise from a mixture of chattering and murmuring?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to come from [Yorkshire dialect](https://web.archive.org/web/20180528183353/http://www.thedialectdictionary.com/view/letter/Yorkshire/970/), with direct meaning of *mutter*.

Also, to me the connection with 'chant' looks interesting:

> **chant (v.)**
> late 14c., from O.Fr. *chanter* "to sing, celebrate" (12c.), from L. *cantare*, frequentative of *canere* "sing," from PIE base **kan-* "to sing" (cf. Gk. *eikanos* "cock," O.E. *hana* "cock," both lit. "bird who sings for sunrise;" O.Ir. *caniaid* "sings," Welsh *canu* "sing"). The frequentative quality of the word was no longer felt in Latin, and by the time French emerged the word had entirely displaced *canere*. Related: Chanted; chanting. The noun is recorded from 1670s, from Fr., from L. *cantus*, from pp. stem of *canere*. — [Etymonline](https://www.etymonline.com/word/chant#etymonline_v_8417)

Comment: It's also used in Scotland. My grandparents used it quite often. "What are you chuntering about?" translates as what are you complaining about.

Comment: @osknows, well wikipedia says: "Broad Yorkshire or Tyke. The dialect has roots in older languages such as Old English and Old Norse; it should not be confused with modern slang."; so if not Old Norse then Old English is common root.

Comment: The OED's third citation (1788) is specifically E. Yorkshire, but the first too (1599 and 1699) are not identifiably connected with Yorkshire (though they might be in text not included).

Comment: I don't find your suggestion of 'chant' persuasive in either sound (in most of the country the vowels would be very different) or meaning.

Comment: And @unreason, the Wikipedia article you refer to does not even mention "chunter" directly: it merely refers to a book which has the word in its title. I agree that this suggests that the authors of the book regarded "chunter" as typically Yorkshire, but really does not amount to a reliable source.

Comment: @Colin Fine, I agree with all you say (except I still maintain possibility of connection to chant); I was not trying to claim authorative and complete answer.

Comment: @Unreason: but discussions on etymology are bedevilled by suggested "connections" without any supporting evidence. The make the whole subject *much* more difficult to track down the reality.

Comment: @Colin Fine, again in ideal world I would completely agree with you, but I fail to see the real, undisputable and unbedevilled difference to "*apparently* of imitative formation". For words which there are no references the only course of action is to speculate. For now I would not modify my answer, but will highlight your pertinent comment.

Comment: We say it here in Hull.
"What you Chuntering about?" ie: moaning. Look at him - Chuntering under his breath - miserable sod!!

Answer (score 1):

I would hazard a guess at a modification of *chant*, which according to [Etymonline](https://www.etymonline.com/word/chant) appeared in the 1600's from the French *chanter*.

Answer (score 0):

The Oxford English Dictionary says "Apparently of imitative formation", and dates it from 1599.

I take it this means imitative of the sound made, rather than being a blend of existing words; but existing words may have had an influence on it.

Comment: I suspect the OED's "apparently of" may translate to "our wild guess is."

Comment: The OED uses _imitative_ for quite a few things, not all of which are particularly imitative in nature. There is—to my knowledge, at least—no such thing as an imitative _formation_ of a word. My immediate thought upon seeing _chunter_ is that it’s a blend of _chatter_ and _mutter_ and _grunt_, all rolled up into one neat package. But then that’s just my ‘apparently of’ guess.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet *There is—to my knowledge, at least—no such thing as an imitative formation of a word.* Formation (OED) **1. a. The action or process of forming**; a putting or coming into form; **creation, production**. Onomatopoeia?

Comment: @Greybeard What I meant (I think – I don’t quite remember writing this comment eight years ago) is that while the resulting word may well be imitative in nature (onomatopoeia, sound symbolism, etc.), I don’t see how its _formation_, that is, the way in which it is created by derivation, borrowing or other means, can be imitative. I suppose if you deliberately coin a word to sound like it was coined in French, that could be considered an ‘imitative formation’, but that’s about as close as I can get, and that doesn’t seem relevant to _chunter_.

Answer (score 0):

According to [Dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/chunter), its origin is from:

> 1590–1600;  orig. dial. (Midlands, N England) chunter, chunder, chunner; — Random House

Interesting to know that the Scottish have a similar word "channer". However, the origin of both words were deemed:

> probably of imitative origin — Collins

I reckon the origin of the word was a result of [*onomatopoeia*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Onomatopoeia). The way "bow-wow" or "meow" were originated from imitating the sounds of dogs and cats, "chunter" was probably imitating murmuring sounds.